# IBM Domino redirects

Tags: redirect, ibm-domino

**Task**

I would like to make following redirect

> http://domain/level1/level2/level3 =>http://domain/level1/level3

I made redirect in settings and it works, however in additional it does also redirect below and I want to avoid it

> http://domain/level1/level2 =>http://domain/level1

My goal is only redirect 3 level URL's and do not touch 2 level URL's.
Is it possible to do?

**Real example**

Since website use substitution I do first substitution for URL I want to redirect

1. Substitution

> /apps/budget/* => /301/apps/budget/*

2. Redirection

> /301/apps/budget/* => https://domain.com/apps/*

I also found similar post (if not the same) here: [IBM Domino url redirect rule processed by closely matching substitution rule](https://serverfault.com/questions/563989/ibm-domino-url-redirect-rule-processed-by-closely-matching-substitution-rule)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wildcard in IBM Domino redirection/substitution rules also match no character:

> /apps/budget/* => /301/apps/budget/*

Will match:

```
/app/budget/anychar
/app/budget/
```

So in your case there is no way with this general rule.

You could specify special rules:

```
/apps/budget/a* => /301/apps/budget/a*
/apps/budget/b* => /301/apps/budget/b*
```

If you need redirctects with more details, you need a proxy server in front of the domino server like IHS or Apache.